# script to embed in android device?

Tags: java, android, python, adb

**Scenario:** I want to embed a script/executable (whatever) into a Android device to control the camera app, take photos open and close the camera app. I have root access to the device.
**Question:** Is  it possible to do by using python/adb? how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access then you can do that easily as you have full access to your device. Using background services and sometimes broadcast receivers you can achieve the scenario explained in the question.

Comment: Thank you I understand, do you have any thoughts or example on how can I do that?

Comment: As rooting is not recommended way in any device as it may damage your device or firmware if not operated properly. So i didn't try this ever.

Comment: @FelipeBarbosa, When asking such broad questions be happy to receive any answers at all. Do not expect any code samples.

Comment: @indramurari Yes, I wouldn't recommend rooting a device too, unless you are testing factory prototypes which usually comes rooted.
I'll try using background services as you suggested, this might help: https://kivy.org/planet/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/

Comment: @FelipeBarbosa  I agree that